# Hide a Nav.Link element when viewed from mobile. (ReactBootstrap,TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I have added a navbar in my react project using reactBootstrap. is there any way to hide one of the navlink when viewed from mobile device.? I am using stylesComponents for styling.

```
const StyledLink = styled(Nav.Link)`
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: ${(props) => (props.active ? "green !important" : "inherit")};
`;
```

```
 <Nav>
     <StyledLink>BACK </StyledLink>
     <StyledLink>HOME </StyledLink>
     <StyledLink active>{props.page}</StyledLink>
 </Nav>
```

is it possible to hide one of the **StyledLink** component if the screen is small without media query?

TIA

Comment: give a class to the element and use @media queries for it, else use `react-responsive` package for completely remove element in breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to set `display: none` or `display: block` based on the device's width.

```
const StyledLink = styled(Nav.Link)`
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: ${(props) => (props.active ? "green !important" : "inherit")};

  @media (min-width: 576px) {
     display: block;
  }
`;
```